Calling Contract Method takes long execution time
I am trying to trigger a contract method on every 30 seconds using matic pos network and i have increased maxPriorityFees and maxFeesPerGas but the issue is i am getting the transaction receipt with in seconds but the contract method execution takes more than 30 seconds which is an issue for me how can improve it so that i can get instant response from the contract
const getFreeData = await provider.getFeeData()
    console.log("getfreeData", getFreeData)

    const triggerTx = await contract.trigger("0x33303a3330", timeMS, new_price, batchSize, {
      gasLimit: gasLimitWithBuffer,
      nonce,
           //  maxPriorityFeePerGas : getFreeData.maxPriorityFeePerGas,
      // maxFeePerGas : getFreeData.maxFeePerGas
      maxPriorityFeePerGas : new BigNumber(getFreeData.maxPriorityFeePerGas).multipliedBy(20).toFixed(0),
      maxFeePerGas : new BigNumber(getFreeData.maxFeePerGas).multipliedBy(20).toFixed(0)
    });
    triggerTx.wait()

Contract Method execution with in seconds
